# Instantiating a Collection Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I have a router class which actually has separate hashes for views and collections as mentioned below. How do i set the url parameter of the collection when i take the instance in a view render method.

The Router Class

```
Router = (function() {
    'use strict';

    var
        viewHash = {},
        collectionsHash = {},
        EvtCalRouter, startRouter;

    // Set up the Backbone Router.
    // Evaluates URL with parameters and maps them to functions contained within the Router.
    // This enables us to do things like allow users to bookmark search results.
    // See "http://backbonejs.org/#Router" for more info.
    EvtCalRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

        // Define the Routes we care about.
        // See "http://backbonejs.org/#Router-routes" for more info.
        routes: {
            "": "home",
            "route1": "route1"
        }
        buildSearchScreen: function() {
            collectionsHash['events'] = ESPN.apps.ADTG.EC.EventsCollection.newInstance({});

        },
        startRouter = function() {
            new EvtCalRouter();
            Backbone.history.start();
        };

        // Start routing functionality
        $(document).ready(startRouter);

        // For any module that needs to know...
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).trigger(ESPN.apps.ADTG.EC.events.ecInit);
        });

        // Public API

        return {
            getCollection: function(name) {
                return collectionsHash[name] || {};
            }
        };

    })();
```

The Collection Class is defined like this

```
Collection = (function() {
    var Events = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        initialize: function(props) {
            this.url = props.url;
            alert(this.url);
        }
    });

    return {
        newInstance: function(options) {
            return new Events(options);
        }
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do i set the url parameter of the collection when i take the
>   instance in a view render method.

You should be able to pass an url in your options hash:

```
Collection.newInstance({url: "your url"});
```

BUT.

To initialize a collection, you need to pass an array of models, so you need to change your collection defintion:

```
Collection = (function(){

  var Events;

  Events = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    initialize: function(models, options){
      this.url = options.url;
      alert(this.url);
    }
  });

  return {
    newInstance : function(models, options) { return new Events(models, options); }
  };
})();
```

I'm not sure why you want to have a dynamic url for your collection though. :/ 
and you probably want to define which model the collection is for...but well, you can pass it thru options as well.

```
Collection.newInstance([
  //array of models...
], {
  url: "meh"
});
```

**EDIT:**

If you need dynamic urls but most part of it are still the same, you can define url as a function:

```
Events = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: function(urlOptions) {
    return 'yourDomain/resources?'+ urlOptions; // just return the url as a string
  }
});
```

**jsfiddle example:**

jsfiddle.net/sbjaz/13

Comment: I want to set the url dynamically because i have heirarchy on the left side of the page clicking on each one of them would retrieve the separate set of data of the same collection.

Comment: then you can define url as a function in your collection. if most part of your url is the same. if they are not, and they point to different controllers, what you really need to do is... to define different collections. See the last added part in my answer.

Comment: I did var eventsCollection = ESPN.apps.ADTG.EC.Router.getCollection('events');
        eventsCollection.url('http://localhost:8080/adtglobal/2.0/api/events?startDate=2013-11-05T00:00:00-0400&endDate=2013-11-06T00:00:00-0400'); I get an error eventsCollection.url is not a function.

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/sbjaz/13/    can you post how you are defining your url function?